# R - Create New Columns from Calculated Percentages With Sum of Data in Several Different Columns & Rows

Tags: r, function, pattern-matching, multiple-columns, percentage

I am looking to take the values from column `Su` in data.frame `df` and create new columns with percentages from row in relationship to the matching categories across all rows in `Ca`,`Tr`,`Sa`, and `ST`

To go from this:

`Ca   Sa   ST   Tr   Su
 A    T1   S    cn   3.2
 A    T2   S    ct   1.7
 C    T1   S    sn   2.1
 H    T3   R    ct   1.4`

To this:

`Ca   Sa   ST   Tr   Su   p_Sa   p_ST   p_Tr   p_Ca
 A    T1   S    cn   3.2  60.4   45.7   100.0  65.3
 A    T2   S    ct   1.7  100.0  24.2   54.8   34.7
 C    T1   S    sn   2.1  39.6   30.0   100.0  100.0
 H    T3   R    ct   1.4  100.0  100.0  45.2   100.0`

where p_Sa is calculated as 100*(value of Su)/(sum of all rows that have the same pattern in column Sa), or - for the first entry: (100*(3.2/(3.2+2.1)));
p_ST = 100*(value of Su)/(sum of all rows that have the same pattern in column ST)
and so on and so forth

I have tried using
`ddply(df, .(Sa), transform, perc.Sa=Su/sum(Su))` 
but I think I may be using it incorrectly and get this error on my actually df that has many more rows and a few additional columns than the example above:

```
Error: Column indexes must be at most 10 if positive, not 17, 35, 64, 79, 108, 128, 145, 173, 189, 230, 244, 255, 296, 310, 337, 353, 374, 408, 418, 441, 477, 493, 525, 551
```

Thank you very much for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution would be to `group_by` each of the columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Sa) %>% mutate(p_Sa = 100*Su/(sum(Su))) %>% ungroup %>%
  group_by(ST) %>%  mutate(p_ST = 100*Su/(sum(Su))) %>% ungroup %>%  
  group_by(Tr) %>%  mutate(p_Tr = 100*Su/(sum(Su))) %>% ungroup %>% 
  group_by(Ca) %>%  mutate(p_Ca = 100*Su/(sum(Su)))


# A tibble: 4 x 9
# Groups:   Ca [3]
#   Ca    Sa    ST    Tr       Su  p_Sa  p_ST  p_Tr  p_Ca
#   <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A     T1    S     cn      3.2  60.4  45.7 100    65.3
# 2 A     T2    S     ct      1.7 100    24.3  54.8  34.7
# 3 C     T1    S     sn      2.1  39.6  30   100   100  
# 4 H     T3    R     ct      1.4 100   100    45.2 100
```

Answer (score 0):

@jasbner solution is completely working, however, here is a more automatised solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  gather(var, val, -Su, -rowid) %>% 
  group_by(val) %>% 
  mutate(res = 100*Su/(sum(Su)),
         var2 = paste("p_", var, sep = "")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  dcast(rowid~var2, first, value.var = "res") %>% 
  right_join(df %>% rowid_to_column(), by = c("rowid" = "rowid")) %>% 
  select(-rowid)

        p_Ca      p_ST      p_Sa      p_Tr Ca Sa ST Tr  Su
1  65.30612  45.71429  60.37736 100.00000  A T1  S cn 3.2
2  34.69388  24.28571 100.00000  54.83871  A T2  S ct 1.7
3 100.00000  30.00000  39.62264 100.00000  C T1  S sn 2.1
4 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000  45.16129  H T3  R ct 1.4
```